# A problem with @ContentChildren and ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an example where I am trying to get all *directives* using `ContentChildren` in wrapper *directive*.

Specifically, I have `LookupContainerDirective` set on a wrapper element. Then, inside the wrapper element, I am have some template and the template itself has `LookupdDirective` in it. I am trying to get all `LookupdDirective` references in `LookupContainerDirective`.

**app.component.html**

```
<div appLookupContainer>
  <!-- <div appLookupd></div> -->
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemp"></ng-container>
</div>  


<ng-template #myTemp>
  <div appLookupd></div>
</ng-template>
```

**lookup-container.directive.ts**

```
@ContentChildren(LookupdDirective, { descendants: true })
private _lookupDirectives: QueryList<LookupdDirective>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this._lookupDirectives);
}
```

I also prepared [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv8n2b) example (check console output).

I expect that the console outputs all references to the `LookupdDirective` but instead it shows that there is none (`_results: Array[0]`). If I don't use the template but regular element then the references are found (`_results: Array[1]`).

Comment: Have a look here, it's similar I think https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20810#issuecomment-401341413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842) about this.

and one suggessted workaround is this;

```html
<div appLookupContainer>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemp"></ng-container>

    <ng-template #myTemp>
        <div appLookupd></div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

as explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842#issuecomment-470167258)

> In Angular content projection and queries it means "content as it was
>   written in a template" and not "content as visible in the DOM" as you
>   seem to expect.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my issue... Although, I would love if they implemented it in a way so my example can work...